# Star Schema Design Help

Tags: data-warehouse, star-schema

I'm stuck on how I would put together a star schema around my current web application (similar structure as stackoverflow). I have:

- Surveys have many Questions

  - Questions have many Votes
- Questions have many Comments

  - Questions, Votes and Comments are all attached to a User and Date

I'm stuck on how I can create a star schema so that I can store and answer questions i.e. How many votes did question a receive today? What were the comments did question b have today and by who?

Any ideas would be helpful!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many votes did a question receive today?

[image]

> What were the comments a question had today and by whom?

[image]

another option...

[image]

Comment: So two facts. That's the way I was going too! Thanks!